# Django: how to prevent parent object to be deleted when deleting its child object

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
Class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Class B(A):
    extra_info = models.CharField()
```

When I delete an B object, its parent object A also gets deleted, how to solve this headache, thanks very much. I'm using Django 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible really in Django 1.2, but it is in Django 1.3, using [`on_delete`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: God, I don't want to invest time to upgrade django, I've used a lot of packages.

Comment: @user469652 - it really shouldn't be very hard - Django 1.3 is largely backwards compatible (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-1-3).

Comment: Does on_delete work even if models are not related using a FK?

Comment: @Guandalino - how else would they be related?

Comment: I dind't realize that model inheritance implies a foreign key.